# How do I pronounce 用勿着 in Shanghainese?

Tags: pronunciation, phrase, tones, shanghainese, ipa

There isn't a pronunciation for it on Wiktionary, and I don't know whether it is a fossilised or an analysable phrase, so therefore I don't know whether or not right-prominent tone sandhi applies. My guess would be:

/ɦi̯ʊŋ²² v̻əʔ⁵⁵ t͡sa̱ʔ²¹/

if it is a fossilised expression and thus right-prominent tone sandhi doesn't apply. Please tell me if I am correct. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the entry for 用勿着 in《[上海方言词典](http://www.shanghainese.info/download/wugniu/%C9%CF%BA%A3%B7%BD%D1%D4%D4%7E%B5%E4.pdf)》on p. 304:

> [image]

Text:

> 【用勿着】
> ɦyoŋ˨˧꜖ uə?˥꜒ za?˨˧꜒꜔
> ⇨ ⟦得⟧ ßiɔ˥꜒ tə?˥꜒꜕

Tone letter to number translation:

> ɦyoŋ²³⁻¹¹ uə?⁵⁵⁻⁵⁵ za?²³⁻⁵³

Tone sandhi is usually represented by back-to-back tone letters. So it looks like the corrected tones are:

> ɦyoŋ¹¹ uə?⁵⁵ za?⁵³

Correct me if I'm wrong, because I have no idea about Shanghainese tones.

---

Here's an entry from a second dictionary [上海话大辞典](http://www.shanghainese.info/download/wugniu/%A1%B6%C9%CF%BA%A3%BB%B0%B4%F3%B4%CA%B5%E4%A1%B7.pdf) p. 274

> [image]

Text:

> 用勿着 ɦioŋ²² vo?⁵⁵ zᴀ?²¹

Comment: Are the dictionaries you used more reliable than Wiktionary? I might use them.

Comment: I always recommend [Pleco](https://www.pleco.com). They have a lot of dictionaries for sale and a lot of free dictionaries that are quite top-notch.

Comment: I think the first notation with tone sandhi is actually: ɦyoŋ¹¹² uə?⁵⁵ za?⁵³ and it looks like the "original" tones are ɦyoŋ¹³ uə?⁵⁵ za?¹³.

Comment: Does Pleco work with Wu Chinese?

Comment: No, not at the moment. You can download those two PDFs I linked above though.

Comment: Ah bon. Thanks for the help